# What's the best practice to iterate a loop within multiple nested hash tables, arrays and current loops?

Tags: .net, powershell

I'm attempting to set a variable that can simplify the redundancy here within these sets of hash tables... I know that what I'm doing can be done, but I'm not sure where to set the anchor or how to touch the index within each loop. Perhaps my method could be better resolved in other ways...

I tried using a for loop outside of the index, wasn't working the way I tried to do it, and so I just multiplied the error output instead of targeting the variables. I also tried putting the additional loop inside of the nested hash tables, and that doesn't actually decrease the amount of instructions any amount at all...

```
$Split       = ( $Config[2..237] ).Split(',')
$Configuration = [Ordered] @{  

Service =@{ 

        Name=@( 0..235 | % { $i = $_ * 11 ; foreach ( $j in ( $Split[ $i + 0  ] ) ) { if ( $j.Contains("_?????") ) { $j.Replace("_?????", $ServiceEnd ) } else { $j } } } ) }

Default =@{ 

        Home=@{ Full =@( 0..235 | % { $i = $_ * 11 ; $Split[ $i + 1  ] } )
                Min  =@( 0..235 | % { $i = $_ * 11 ; $Split[ $i + 2  ] } ) }

        Pro =@{ Full =@( 0..235 | % { $i = $_ * 11 ; $Split[ $i + 3  ] } )
                Min  =@( 0..235 | % { $i = $_ * 11 ; $Split[ $i + 4  ] } ) } }

Safe    =@{

        Desk=@{ Full =@( 0..235 | % { $i = $_ * 11 ; $Split[ $i + 5  ] } )
                Min  =@( 0..235 | % { $i = $_ * 11 ; $Split[ $i + 6  ] } ) }

        Lap =@{ Full =@( 0..235 | % { $i = $_ * 11 ; $Split[ $i + 7  ] } )
                Min  =@( 0..235 | % { $i = $_ * 11 ; $Split[ $i + 8  ] } ) } }

Tweaked =@{

        Desk=@{ Full =@( 0..235 | % { $i = $_ * 11 ; $Split[ $i + 9  ] } )
                Min  =@( 0..235 | % { $i = $_ * 11 ; $Split[ $i + 10 ] } ) } } }
```

I'm not looking to touch the first array, because that's doing exactly what I want it to do. The rest of them however, I have a feeling that they can all be written out to a similar result of [ $i + 1..10 ] or something. That's sort of the objective I'm after.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the following is an example using `Group-Object`.

```
$i = 0
$h = $Config[2..237].Split(',') | Group-Object { $i % 11; $script:i++ } -AsHashTable

$Configuration2 = [Ordered]@{  
    Service = @{
        Name = $h[0].Replace("_?????", $ServiceEnd)
    }
    Default = @{ 
        Home = @{ Full = $h[1]; Min = $h[2] }
        Pro  = @{ Full = $h[3]; Min = $h[4] } 
    }
    Safe = @{
        Desk = @{ Full = $h[5]; Min = $h[6] }
        Lap  = @{ Full = $h[7]; Min = $h[8] }
    }
    Tweaked = @{
        Desk = @{ Full = $h[9]; Min = $h[10] }
    } 
}
```

I think that it may be treated simply as CSV.

```
$data = $Config[2..237] | ConvertFrom-Csv -Header (0..10)
$data.0
```

Comment: Using as a CSV is great and all, but I wanted the CSV output to be incorporated into the script without conversion, basically I wanted to make it possible to alter or amend the CSV info without an out-file